# Unobtrusive javascript drivers for Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dojo, unobtrusive-javascript, ujs

I have spent some hours looking for a Rails3 dojo-toolkit UJS-driver but I had no luck.
Google, github, the dojo official site and different blogs didn't help me.

It seems like rails3 has only three drivers actually written.
These are the drivers I found:

Two officials:

- [Prototype-UJS](https://github.com/rails/prototype-ujs) (default in rails 3.0).
- [jQuery-UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) (optional, it will be the default option in rails 3.1).

Two unofficials:

- [Mootools-UJS](https://github.com/kevinvaldek/mootools-ujs)
- [Dojo-UJS](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojox/trunk/rails/README)

We could complete this list with the existing ujs-drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [dojox.rails](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojox/trunk/rails/README), though I'm only looking at it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Bob Remeika's [d-rails](https://github.com/foobarfighter/drails)  Not sure whether this supports Rails3

Comment: Thanks Peller, I have read about drails but it is not a rails3 ujs-driver. Drails is an rails2 alternavite to prototype.

Comment: you're absolutely right.  dojox.rails is the new place for his code.